# Deduplicator function is failing to remove repeats on random iterations

Tags: javascript

Newbie to JS. With help from a fellow dev, I have the following solution:

```js
const data = {
  "Total_packages": {
    "package1": {
      "tags": [
        "kj21",
        "j1",
        "sj2",
        "z1"
      ],
      "expectedResponse": [{
        "firstName": "Name",
        "lastName": "lastName",
        "purchase": [{
          "title": "title",
          "category": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "package2": {
      "tags": [
        "s2",
        "dsd3",
        "mhg",
        "sz7"
      ],
      "expectedResponse": [{
        "firstName": "Name1",
        "lastName": "lastName1",
        "purchase": [{
          "title": "title1",
          "category": [
            "a1",
            "b1",
            "c1"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "package3": {
      "tags": [
        "s21",
        "dsd31",
        "mhg1",
        "sz71"
      ],
      "expectedResponse": [{
        "firstName": "Name2",
        "lastName": "lastName2",
        "purchase": [{
          "title": "title2",
          "category": [
            "a2",
            "b2",
            "c2"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "package4": {
      "tags": [
        "s22",
        "dsd32",
        "mhg2",
        "sz72"
      ],
      "expectedResponse": [{
        "firstName": "Name3",
        "lastName": "lastName3",
        "purchase": [{
          "title": "title3",
          "category": [
            "a3",
            "b3",
            "c3"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "package5": {
      "tags": [
        "s22",
        "dsd32",
        "mhg2",
        "sz72"
      ],
      "expectedResponse": [{
        "firstName": "Name4",
        "lastName": "lastName4",
        "purchase": [{
          "title": "title4",
          "category": [
            "a4",
            "b4",
            "c4"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
}

var arrRand = genNum(data, 4);
console.log(arrRand);

function genNum(data, loop = '') {
  var list = [];
  var arrayOfTags = Object.entries(data.Total_packages).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if (v.tags) acc = acc.concat(v.tags.map(t => ({
      tag: t,
      response: v.expectedResponse
    })));
    return acc;
  }, []);

  for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfTags.length);
    var randomTag = arrayOfTags[randomIndex];
    list.push(randomTag);
  }
  return list;

  let output = list.filter((item, index) => {
    return list.filter((item2, index2) => {
      return ((item.tag === item2.tag) && (index2 < index));
    }).length === 0;
  });
  return output;
}
```

Goal: Write a function to pick a random "tags" value and its respective "expectedResponse" value.

It works well most of the time, however, when I am doing iterations of around 6-8 times (with a list that contains three times as many "tags" values), I am getting duplicates.

In my code, I am declaring a variable that is then set to the variable that contains the final list of the sanitized data. I then iteratively call that data by index (i.e arrRand[1]), and use it to validate. This is where I see the issue.

Comment: The code after `return list` is unreachable.  Do you understand why?

Comment: @Wyck no,  I don't unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  Give [Warning: unreachable code after return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return) a quick read.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid getting duplicate tags, we use a couple of .reduce() calls to return only unique tags.

Once the array of tags is generated, we shuffle then take the first `count` items to avoid duplicates.

The `shuffle()` function used here is a basic [Fisher–Yates / Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

```js
const data = { "Total_packages": { "package1": { "tags": [ "kj21", "j1", "sj2", "z1" ], "expectedResponse": [ { "firstName": "Name", "lastName": "lastName", "purchase": [ { "title": "title", "category": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } ] } ] }, "package2": { "tags": [ "s2", "dsd3", "mhg", "sz7" ], "expectedResponse": [ { "firstName": "Name1", "lastName": "lastName1", "purchase": [ { "title": "title1", "category": [ "a1", "b1", "c1" ] } ] } ] }, "package3": { "tags": [ "s21", "dsd31", "mhg1", "sz71" ], "expectedResponse": [ { "firstName": "Name2", "lastName": "lastName2", "purchase": [ { "title": "title2", "category": [ "a2", "b2", "c2" ] } ] } ] }, "package4": { "tags": [ "s22", "dsd32", "mhg2", "sz72" ], "expectedResponse": [ { "firstName": "Name3", "lastName": "lastName3", "purchase": [ { "title": "title3", "category": [ "a3", "b3", "c3" ] } ] } ] }, "package5": { "tags": [ "s22", "dsd32", "mhg2", "sz72" ], "expectedResponse": [ { "firstName": "Name4", "lastName": "lastName4", "purchase": [ { "title": "title4", "category": [ "a4", "b4", "c4" ] } ] } ] } } } 
 
function shuffle(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function genNum(data, count) {
  const uniqueTags = Object.values(Object.values(data.Total_packages).reduce((acc, v) => {
    return (v.tags || []).reduce((acc, tag) => {
      acc[tag] = acc[tag] || { tag, response: v.expectedResponse };
      return acc;
    }, acc)
  }, []));

  return shuffle(uniqueTags).slice(0, count);
}

var arrRand = genNum(data, 4);
console.log(arrRand);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Really like the destructuring assignment to do the swap in the shuffle